# Why do I get an error when trying to console log my $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

Sorry im new to jquery I usually use php/html. Can you tell why my code wont console log the VAR values. I am building an array from my vars when looping through them. I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y4ejfse/)

```
    var string1 = "tes£$%t";
    var string2 = "test";
    var string3 = "test";
    var string4 = "test";

    var check_fields = [string1, string2, string3, string4];

    $.each(check_fields, function(index, value) {

        if (value.replace(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i, "") != string) {
        console.log(value);

        }

    });
```

Comment: It is working man! https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9y4ejfse/1/ Just include `jQuery` library..

Comment: You didn't include jquery.js file in your page, that's why `$ is not defined`

Comment: That means you haven't included jquery library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: JQuery is an external library, it doesn't comw with JS

Comment: How do I add it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Thankyou. That has solved the first part of my question. I have added a the last piece of my code to the comment above. I still get an undefined error?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine but jquery file is missing here.
  **Fiddle link:-** In the left side under the external resource just put the jquery cdn path and click on run then check.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: Like you, I was confused by the new JS Fiddle interface. The jQuery setting is now here: http://i.imgur.com/sCHlbcN.png

Comment: This is good, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

include the jquery header file in the head your html code

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html file is missing the external jQuery library.
Try adding this to the start of your html file (preferably in the head, of in the case of JSFiddle just paste it into the HTML box):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this works